# Pandas get row if column is a substring of string

Tags: pandas

I can do the following if I want to extract rows whose column "A" contains the substring "hello".

```
df[df['A'].str.contains("hello")]
```

How can I select rows whose column is the substring for another word? e.g.

```
df["hello".contains(df['A'].str)]
```

Here's an example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A":["hel"]})
df["hello".contains(df['A'].str)]
```

Comment: can you post an example input?

Comment: Can you [mcve] to the question? It makes everyone's life easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Pandas dataframe by columns that are a substring of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77212886/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-columns-that-are-a-substring-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could apply [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['hell', 'world', 'hello'], columns=['A'])
res = df[df['A'].apply("hello".find).ne(-1)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
       A
0   hell
2  hello
```

As an alternative use [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

```
res = df[df['A'].apply("hello".__contains__)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
       A
0   hell
2  hello
```

Or simply:

```
res = df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x in "hello")]
print(res)
```

Comment: thank you! the lambda method is the most intuitive one