# Filter Pandas dataframe by columns that are a substring of a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring, contains

I am trying to filter a dataframe using the condition that string values in a column are a substring of a string outside of the dataframe. Example below:

```
df = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['hello', 'bye', 'hello']]

reference_str = "hello there"

output = ['a','c']
```

One way is perhaps to iterate through every value in the column using regex. Was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nick `contains` wouldn't really work here as the opposite match is wanted ;)  (the logic is still a bit unclear)

Comment: @randomwerg can you please provide a valid DataFrame constructor? Do you only have full matches for words?

Comment: @Nick I see, I read too quickly ;) I can't say I'm fond of the method though

Comment: I'd use the third one with a list comprehension instead of `apply`, not sure it's worth a separate answer.

Comment: Thank you Nick and Mozway for the helpful solutions! Apologies for the poor syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match full words, you could use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) on the split string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'col2': ['hello', 'bye', 'hello']})

reference_str = "hello there"

out = df[df['col2'].isin(reference_str.split())]

print(out)
```

If really, you want to match any substring (for instance `'the'` or `'el'` should match), then you have to loop:

```
out = df[[x in reference_str for x in df['col2']]]
```

Output:

```
  col1   col2
0    a  hello
2    c  hello
```

Comment: Do you know why `df.query(z in @reference_str)` does not work on this (after naming the column z)?  I tried that thinking it would be cleaner syntax, but it doesn't return any rows for this example.

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? `query` takes a string as input: `df.query('z in @reference_str')`

Comment: Doesn't work in that `df.query('col2 in @reference_str')` returns empty on your sample data.  However, if I change `'col2': [5, 1, 9]` and define `reference_tup = (5,7,9)`, then `df2.query('col2 in @reference_tup')` returns two rows, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Out of interest I ran timings on the techniques in @mozway answer and the answers proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565809/pandas-get-row-if-column-is-a-substring-of-string) using some fairly big data (100k rows in dataframe, 1000 word reference string). To summarise:

```py
# isin (works for whole words only, could have issues with punctuation in reference string)
out = df[df['col2'].isin(reference_str.split())]

# list comprehension
out = df[[x in reference_str for x in df['col2']]]

# apply with str.find
# note slightly modified as .ge(0) is faster than .ne(-1)
out = df[df['col2'].apply(reference_str.find).ge(0)]

# apply with str.__contains__
out = df[df['col2'].apply(reference_str.__contains__)]

# apply with in
out = df[df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x in reference_str)]
```

I used words from the [nltk toolkit](https://www.nltk.org/) for test data. This is the test script (using `isin` for the example):

```
timeit.timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd
import random
from nltk.corpus import words

N = 1000
wordlist = words.words()
strs = random.choices(wordlist, k=N*100)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1' : range(N*100), 'col2' : strs })
reference_str = ' '.join(random.choices(wordlist, k=N))
''', stmt='''
out = df[df['col2'].isin(reference_str.split())]
''', number=1)
```

For matching whole words, the `isin` technique is far and away the fastest, about 80x the speed of any of the other variants.

| Variant | Time | Ratio (isin) | Ratio (find) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| isin | 0.013 | 1 | 0.014 |
| find | 0.917 | 70.5 | 1 |
| list comp | 1.050 | 80.1 | 1.14 |
| contains | 1.054 | 81.1 | 1.15 |
| in | 1.066 | 82 | 1.16 |

However should a substring search be necessary, a `find` is the most efficient, about 15% faster than the other techniques.